# Using JavaScript's Selenium Webdriver, how to launch Chrome with a specific path to chrome.exe?

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I have the following Javascript code that launches Chrome with the path to Chrome specified by the `PATH` environment variable.

```
    let driver = await new Builder()
        .forBrowser('chrome')
        .build();
```

How can I launch Chrome with a specific path to Chrome? I would love something like this:

```
    let driver = await new Builder()
        .forBrowser('chrome')
        .withPath('C:\\temp\\chrome.exe')
        .build();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably need to use ChromeOptions to setup custom chrome.exe

```
const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
const chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');
const builder = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('chrome');

const chromeOptions = new chrome.Options();
chromeOptions.setChromeBinaryPath("/path/to/chrome.exe");
builder.setChromeOptions(chromeOptions);
const driver = builder.build();
```

[Documentation](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/chrome_exports_Options.html) for *chrome.Options*