# Using JavaScript's Selenium Webdriver, how to launch Chrome with a specific path to chromedriver.exe?

Tags: javascript, typescript, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I have the following Javascript code that launches Chrome with the path to chromedriver.exe specified by the PATH environment variable. This question is different than [how to launch Chrome with a specific chrome.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58141553/using-javascripts-selenium-webdriver-how-to-launch-chrome-with-a-specific-path) because chromedriver.exe is a standalone server that takes in commands from Selenium Server and uses JSON commands to talk to the Chrome browser's API. You need both chrome.exe and chromedriver.exe to launch a Chrome browser with Selenium.

```
    let driver = await new Builder()
        .forBrowser('chrome')
        .build();
```

However, I would like to clear my PATH environment variable and instead set a path from within the code that launches Chrome, something like the below. How can I do that please?

```
    let driver = await new Builder()
        .forBrowser('chrome')
        .withDriverPath('C:\\temp\\chromedriver.exe')
        .build();
```

Comment: Because javascript code process in client. How do you know PATH or chromedriver.exe exists in client?

Comment: @AuNguyen You can run Javascript with Node.js

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using JavaScript's Selenium Webdriver, how to launch Chrome with a specific path to chrome.exe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58141553/using-javascripts-selenium-webdriver-how-to-launch-chrome-with-a-specific-path)

Comment: @lp177 This is not a duplicate of the above question because the above asks about a specific path to chrome.exe, not chromedriver.exe. They are different.

Comment: @lp177 I have edited the question to describe the differences between chrome.exe and chromedriver.exe. Thank you for pointing this out because it wasn't clear in the original question. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In reading https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js

At line 212

It seem posible to set in your environ variables a value for CHROMEDRIVER_EXE

Comment: I ended up setting the PATH environment variable: `process.env["PATH"] = "<insert path to directory containing Chrome here>";` And it worked!